# How to download a website page content like save as?

Tags: c#, winforms

When i'm doing save as it's saving/downloading everything including images.

I tried to make this class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MyTests
{
    class Download
    {
        public void Dowlnoading()
        {
            WebClient wchtml = new WebClient();
            string htmlString = wchtml.DownloadString("https://myfiles.com");
            int mastercount = 0;
            Regex regPattern = new Regex(@"http://i.imgur.com/(.*?)alt=""", RegexOptions.Singleline);
            MatchCollection matchImageLinks = regPattern.Matches(htmlString);

            foreach (Match img_match in matchImageLinks)
            {
                string imgurl = img_match.Groups[1].Value.ToString();
                Regex regx = new Regex("http://([\\w+?\\.\\w+])+([a-zA-Z0-9\\~\\!\\@\\#\\$\\%\\^\\&amp;\\*\\(\\)_\\-\\=\\+\\\\\\/\\?\\.\\:\\;\\'\\,]*)?",
                RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                MatchCollection ms = regx.Matches(imgurl);
                foreach (Match m in ms)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Downloading..  " + m.Value);
                    mastercount++;
                    try
                    {
                        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
                        wc.DownloadFile(m.Value, @"D:\_Images\bg_" + mastercount + ".gif");
                        Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    }
                    catch (Exception x)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Failed to download image.");
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

using it in form1

```
public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Downloading dl = new Downloading();
            dl.DowlnoadLatest();
        }
```

when running the app it's holding for 10-13 seconds but then when I'm looking at the folder on the hard disk i see that nothing have been downloaded.

Comment: Are you sure your regexes are matching the links you want? Have you considered using a HTML parser like HtmlAgilityPack?

Comment: You cannot get the whole content of that page with WebClient, the HTML is generated by scripts (also Angular Materials). You should use a WebBrowser class (WebView2) and get the items you want from the cache when the page competes.

Comment: @Jimi seems hard.  i will try. thanks.